# Viewing preview of files in finder

Tags: macos, finder

I have some .groovy files on my file system.  I would like to be able to preview them in Finder as I navigate around them.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/) displays files with no extension or with arbitrary extensions as plain text. You can install it by moving the qlgenerator bundle to `~/Library/QuickLook/` and running `qlmanage -r`.

If it doesn't display some file types, try adding their UTIs to `CFBundleDocumentTypes:LSContentTypes` in the Info.plist.

Answer (score 2):

If Finder does not automatically show a preview of a file when using QuickLook (default shortcut key is <kbd>Space</kbd> when file is selected), then the QuickLook extension does not support these files.

Unless you're a hard-core Mac/Unix developer, you won't be able to add this capability yourself. Never fear, however; this *is* the Internet, after all, and odds are that someone's already developed the plugin for this. A good place to look is the [QuickLook Plugins](http://quicklookplugins.com/) site.

Wherever you get your plugins, installation is very simple. Drag the plugin file (it will look something like a little white Lego brick) to the `/Library/QuickLook/` folder, log out, and log back in again. If everything is working properly, you should be able to press <kbd>Space</kbd> with your `.groovy` file selected and see the QuickLook window appear with a preview.

Notes: You will probably need an admin username/password to modify the `/Library/QuickLook/` folder. Also, if QuickLook still doesn't show a preview after logging back in, try restarting your computer.